# Как в прологе правильно описать логический вентиль?

Tags: prolog

Логический вентиль можно было бы описать таким образом:

```
pred_or(1, 1).
pred_or(1, 0).
pred_or(0, 1).
```

И аналогично остальные предикаты. Но, возможно, есть более правильный способ, чтобы указать согласно таблице истинности, на каких комбинациях какому значению будет приравниваться выход вентиля (0 и 1). Вышеописанный способ правильный? Или лучше как-то по-другому делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен предикат, то ваш вариант правильный. Если нужна функция с описанием всех вариантов (не только истинных), то добавляете третий параметр (выходной), там прописываете результат согласно таблице истинности:

```
func_or(1, 1, 1).
func_or(1, 0, 1).
func_or(0, 1, 1).
func_or(0, 0, 0).
```